# Unable to delete a previous array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am going to design a live search engine, taking the array from a database. When I am running this code, it is giving the current results with the previous result. I want to remove the previous results. Here is my code in Javascript.

```
var searchTable=document.getElementById('searchResults');<br>
var tbody=searchTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var queryResult=http.responseText;
var keyArray=queryResult.split("|");
keyArray.shift();
var arrayLength=keyArray.length;
//console.log(keyArray);
var y=document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
for(var i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) {
    var trEl=document.createElement("tr");
    var tdEl=document.createElement("td");
    var trtdEl=trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
    var textNode=document.createTextNode(keyArray[i]);
    trtdEl.appendChild(textNode);
    y.insertBefore(trEl,y.firstChild);
}
```

Please help me guys..

Comment: Help us help you...what exactly are you trying to do to the array? where are you trying to do it? What have you tried, and why isn't it working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: actually i am going to design a live search. in this i have taken an array i.e. 'y' which is the element of html tbody where i want to put the search results. when i have append the result first then it is ok. but when i press the next key then the new result is appended to the previous one. now i want to delete the previous result. for ex. i have a list of three persons raj, rohit, ram when i press r then result is rohit,ram,raj and when i press ra then result is 'raj,ram,rohit,ram, raj' but i need only 'raj,ram'.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `for` loop, you must remove all the children of the element `y`. Put something like this:

```
while (y.firstChild) y.removeChild(y.firstChild);
```